# Android posting the full array to php

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

I am retrieving contacts from android phone, then want to send the data to php as an array and loop over the results and send, instead, it only finds the last contact. Any suggestions on how i can post the whole array.

Here is my current code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList alContacts;
    ArrayList alNumbers;
    Button button;
    EditText Name,Email;
    Map<String,String> param;
    ListView lv;
    Cursor cr;
    String URL ="http://192.168.0.10/oap/home/synchcontacts";
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        Name= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // getDetails();
                final String name,email;
                name = Name.getText().toString();
                email = Email.getText().toString();

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        builder.setTitle("Server Title");
                        builder.setMessage(response);
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog bu = builder.create();
                        bu.show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver(); //Activity/Application android.content.Context
                        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
                        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
                        {
                            alContacts = new ArrayList<String>();
                            alNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
                            do
                            {
                                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                                if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
                                {
                                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{ id }, null);
                                    while (pCur.moveToNext())
                                    {
                                        String contactNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                                       alContacts.add(name);
                                       alNumbers.add(contactNumber);

                                        break;
                                    }
                                    pCur.close();
                                }


                            } while (cursor.moveToNext()) ;
                            List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                            JsonArray myContacts = gson.toJsonTree(alContacts).getAsJsonArray();
                            JsonArray myNumbers = gson.toJsonTree(alNumbers).getAsJsonArray();
                            for (int i=0; i<myContacts.size();i++){
                                param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name[]",myContacts.get(i).toString()));
                                param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone[]",myNumbers.get(i).toString()));

                            }
                             Log.i("PARAM",param.toString());
                        }

                        return param;

                    }
                };
                MySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

            }
        });


    }

}
```

php

```
   function SynchContacts() {

        $phone = $this->input->post('phone');
        $name = $this->input->post('name');       


        for ($i = 0; $i < count($phone); $i++) {
            $data = array(
                'name' => $name[$i],
                'phone' => $phone[$i]
            );
            $this->saveData('phonebook', $data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using HashMap to pass the values. And for hashMap you are storing only the last value, cause you cannot have 2 items with the same id.

You might want to use something like a list internally and then render the request from that.

For example with item as (org.apache.http.NameValuePair):

```
    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id[]", "id1"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id[]", "id2"));
    ....
```

So, in your case that would be:

```
        ....
        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        JsonArray myContacts = gson.toJsonTree(alContacts).getAsJsonArray();
        JsonArray myNumbers = gson.toJsonTree(alNumbers).getAsJsonArray();
        for (int i=0; i<myContacts.size();i++){
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name[]",myContacts.get(i).toString()));
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone[]",myNumbers.get(i).toString()));
        }

        return param;
```

EDIT:

Seems after seeing the whole snipset it seems that you are limited by the library you are using. I think, you will find answer in following links:

[Google Volley request with duplicate parameter names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999963/google-volley-request-with-duplicate-parameter-names)

Or here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/volley-users/tFRclnEbpAk

Comment: @Valdimir Thank you for sharing, using your suggestion how do i replace the hashmap with the list then return the final output to be sent to the server

Comment: @Alphy I've updated my example to look more like your code snipset. How to modify code where you use param later I cant say, since its not part of your shared snipset.

Comment: @Valdimir I have updated the snipet to the full code, From the log i can see it is creating the arrays, one problem though, the return value seems not to work since now I am using the List<NameValuePair> how will this method change  protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {  in reference to the update?

Comment: @Alphy now you return List<NameValuePair>

Comment: @Valdimir I understand that, the problem is incompatible types , this method "Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError { " is a map, while the array created is a name value pair List, if i cast like this "return (Map<String><String>) param;" it returns blank

Comment: @Alphy ok. now I see the problem. it wasn't obvious in the original snipset that you are bound by some library. See the edited part.

Comment: @Valdimir Thank you, I am looking at the links